# Historical Origin of Deities

Tags: vedas, shiva, vishnu, krishna, brahma

Current Hinduism knows several deities as Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, Krishna, ... , each having a meaning in the same religious/philosophical context.

According to source research, have all these deities been part of the same tradition or do the names come from different religions that have melted into the present form of Hinduism?

Comment: All the major deities which are worshiped today either have directly base in the Vedas or have link to Vedas in some or other way: eg. Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, Devi, etc.. all come from Vedas.. while of Lord Vishnu also there are several incarnations like Varaha, Rama, Krishna, etc.. of Lord Shiva also there are several incarnations like Durvasa, Pipplada, etc... so there are various links and connections...

Comment: @Tezz My question was mainly an idea because such phenomena can be observed in Judaism and Zostrianism. If you put your answer as an answer, and you know that your answer is right, I could accept it... :)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am not a Hindu (nor is my auntie) and so I have no overview on available sources. Maybe my question is stupid for those who know better.

Comment: @Jeschu don't bother to reply to rude and unwelcoming comments. Just flag them. There is nothing wrong with your Q. Please don't get demoralized by the above comment and try to continue to participate on the site.

Answer (score 1):

There are two examples, I can think of that meet what your last question is looking for. [Harinagara and Bindulaa](https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/pratisarga-parva-third-khand.pdf). Although technically they are not mentioned as deities in the religion they are originally mentioned in (as in humans reading). You can tell it is a reference to the four horses of the four horsemen of the apocalypse in Christianity from the mention of Christianity earlier in the story, their colors, and the fact an unnamed avatar of Vishnu is foretold to help the evil Kali (after he gets a boon). It being Harinagara fits nicely with his destructive wake in Christianity.

> Soot jee said:-" The dharmic king Deshraaj had worshipped and served lord Sun
> about twelve years continuously. After that lord Surya (Sun) got pleased with him
> and told him: - "Ask any boon from me”. He said: - "Dev! (Lord!) I bow towards
> you, if you want to give me anything as a boon then please provide me the horse
> that can fly in the sky." Having accepted his want, he gave him Papihaa (the one
> who protects every lokas) named horse. After that, Papihaa named horse, who
> protects every lokas, have been stuck by arrow of Madana and cannot control his
> sex and begat with Harinee named divine mare. Which cause divine Harinee to
> produce pale colored male horse named Manoratha (Manohaaraa) and black
> colored male horse named Karaala (frightful). The both came same time from that
> single womb and they were part of Shabya (one of the warrior in Mahabharata)
> and Sugriva (important character in Ramayana). **After that from the part of Jishnu
> and Vishnu there took birth two horses from the womb of Harinee. One is
> Meghapushpa (divine name), which is golden in color and was named Bindulaa
> (Bendulaa) and other is Balahaak (divine name) which is white in color like snow
> and was named Harinagara.** This were the first four horses produced from the
> divine horse Harinee and Papihaa and from those four divine flying horses, many

By the way, all four horses are important to the rest of the main story.

Comment: That's also an interesting point in comparative religion although not really the answer to my question

Comment: @Jeschu Well its the historical origin of Harinagara and Bindulaa, who are definitely deities.